# Default move constructor failing when used in a constexpr context,

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, visual-studio-2022, move-constructor

I have an issue with the default move constructor in **Visual Studio 2022 (/std:c++latest)** in a constexpr context. I do not see the issue in **Visual Studio 2019**. I have two questions:

- Is it my code or Visual Studio 2022 that is incorrect? If my code is incorrect then why?
- Are similar issues are seen in gcc or clang? (I do currently have access to those compilers.)

**Problem statement**
In the code below, I have two true/false switches:
`DEFAULT_MOVE` and `CONSTEXPR`, therefore giving me four possible programs.

- `DEFAULT_MOVE` controls whether the default move constuctor or a
  home-brew move constructor is used.
- `CONSTEXPR` controls whether an instance of `Container` is created at
  compile-time or run-time.

The code **does not** compile when both `DEFAULT_MOVE` and `CONSTEXPR` are both true, yielding the message:
*error C3615: constexpr function 'Containerstd::u8string_view,3::Container' cannot result in a constant expression*

However, under any other of the three switch combinations the code **compiles successfully**.

I would have expected the code to compile in all four cases.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <string_view>

//switches
#define DEFAULT_MOVE true
#define CONSTEXPR true

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct Container{
  std::array<T, N> x; 

  template<typename... Args>
  constexpr explicit Container(Args&&...args) : x{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}

#if DEFAULT_MOVE
  //default move ctor
  constexpr Container(Container&&) noexcept = default;
#else
  //home-brew move ctor
  constexpr Container(Container&& other) noexcept : x{} {
    for (size_t n{0} ; T& e : other.x)
      x[n++] = std::move(e);
  }
#endif

  constexpr Container(const Container&) = delete;
  constexpr Container& operator=(Container&&) = delete;
  constexpr Container& operator=(const Container&) = delete;
  constexpr ~Container() = default;
};

using X = Container<std::u8string_view, 3>;
using Y = Container<X, 2>;

int main() {
#if CONSTEXPR
  // constexpr creation of a Y object
  constexpr Y a{X{u8"a",u8"b"}, X{u8"a"}};
  static_assert(a.x[0].x[1] == u8"b");

#else
  // runtime creation of a Y object
  const Y a{X{u8"a",u8"b"}, X{u8"a"}};
  assert(a.x[0].x[1] == u8"b");
#endif  
}
```

Comment: This issue has been resolved in the latest version of Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use: `constexpr Container(Container&&) = default;`. The default implementation is already `noexcept` in most cases.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec):

> default constructors, copy constructors, move constructors that are implicitly-declared or defaulted on their first declaration unless:
>
> - a constructor for a base or member that the implicit definition of the constructor would call is potentially-throwing
> - a subexpression of such an initialization, such as a default argument expression, is potentially-throwing
> - a default member initializer (for default constructor only) is potentially-throwing

Best way to validate things like this is using https://godbolt.org/. It let's you try out a lot of different compilers quickly.

> Add `#include <cstddef>` to make `size_t` work without `std::size`.

Clang/LLVM v13 can build this with `-std=c++20`, as can Visual C++ as with `/std:c++20` (19.30 on godbolt is VS 2022's compiler).

I tried `/std:c++latest` and it also works.

What is the full set of compiler switches you are using? Also try `cl -Bv` and see what version of the compiler exactly you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I should have thought about godbolt! I will get back to you with the compiler settings soon.

Comment: Compiler version is 19.30.30709 for x86) in visual studio v17.0.5.

Comment: swtiches are: /permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Debug\" /GS /W4 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"..\..\icu\icu4c\include" /Zi /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"<mypath>\x64\Debug\util.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /U"NDEBUG" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_LIB" /D "NOMINMAX" /errorReport:prompt /WX /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MDd /std:c++latest /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\util.pch" /diagnostics:column